# How to reattach PubSub subscription to topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In Google Cloud PubSub you tipically have subscriptions attached to a topic. I saw a new option to "detach" a subscription from the topic.

My app was having issues so I detached the subscription from the topic instead of deleting it, I thought it was an easy way to "give my app a break". The issue is, it seems that I cannot reattach the subscription to the topic anymore.

According to this document I can infer that it is not possible to get a subscription to reattach to a topic: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#detaching_subscriptions

My questions are:

1. is there a way to reactivate a subscription after it has been detached (I assume no).
2. what is the recommended way to put a "pause" to a subscription in order to give my system some breath room until I get it back up?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you're seeing "This subscription has been detached from its topic." you can edit the Subscription and resave it to reattach.

Comment: interesting... I just tried what you said and it sort of worked... the subscription appeared to be attached again, but, when I try to detach again it shows an error message, are you sure this is a feature of pubsub? because when detaching there is a warning saying "... this action cannot be undone..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#detaching_subscriptions),

> After the Pub/Sub service detaches the subscription from the topic,
> the Pub/Sub service deletes any messages that it retains for the
> subscription. **You can't retrieve these messages from the subscription
> or reattach the subscription** to a topic.

---

Regarding the **pause**, there is no such option, however, if you are having a [**pull**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#pull-subscription) subscription, you control when to initiate requests to the Pub/Sub server to retrieve messages.

Thus, if you are having a [**push**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push-subscription) subscription, you can [change it to pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#change_pull_push) in order to temporarily stop Pub/Sub from sending requests to the push endpoint, and then set the URL to a valid endpoint again to resume push delivery - [*Stopping and resuming delivery*](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#stopping_and_resuming_delivery).

Comment: thanks, I think it is strange that there is no straightforward way to stop a subscription without workarounds, I guess I wil have to do with this suggestion

Comment: I agree with you but I think that currently it is designed to be this way, as this is documented like a normal workflow to temporarily stop the *push* subscription.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please accept it for a better visibility within the community.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. What is the difference between `detach` a subscription vs. `delete` a subscription?